# wso2esb payloadfactory build JSON message

Tags: json, rest, mediator, wso2-esb

I am trying to use wso2esb 4.7.0 REST API to implement following use case:

Expose a REST resource that when you do a GET request it builds a JSON message and makes a POST request to a backend service and receives a JSON response that will be returned to the client.

I am having problems building the JSON message. I am using the payloadfactory mediator to build my JSON request, but I am only getting an empty soap message on my backend service.

Here is the REST API source config I am using:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test" context="/test">
 <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/test">
  <inSequence>
     <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>{"request": "Hello JSON!"}</format>
        <args/>
     </payloadFactory>
     <property name="Content-Type" value="application/json" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
     <send>
        <endpoint name="HTTPEndpoint">
           <http method="POST" uri-template="http://localhost:8080"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
     <log level="full"/>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
 </resource>
</api>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the "messageType" property as follows before the send mediator.

```
    <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

So your configuration should be changed as follows.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test" context="/test">
 <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/test">
    <inSequence>
     <payloadFactory media-type="json">
          <format>{"request": "Hello JSON!"}</format>
        <args/>
     </payloadFactory>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
     <send>
      <endpoint name="HTTPEndpoint">
       <http method="POST" uri-template="http://localhost:8080"/>
      </endpoint>
    </send>
   <log level="full"/>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
   <send/>
  </outSequence>
 </resource>
</api>
```